# Where is WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(Uri,CancellationToken) in VS11

Tags: c#, async-ctp, visual-studio-2012

In the Async CTP there is an extension method with the signature

```
WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(Uri,CancellationToken)
```

Where is this in VS11?
Do I need to install the Async CTP to get this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET 4.5, you would probably use the new [HttpClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in particular the [GetStringAsync Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551746%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Alas, HttpClient.GetStringAsync doesn't have a version that takes a cancellationToken, so that task is not canceled more gracefully than the WebClient would be canceled.

Answer (score 2):

It's unfortunate that CancellationToken support isn't built in, but here's how you can approximate it by leveraging the Register and CancelAsync methods:

```
var downloadTask = webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(source);

string text;
using (cancellationToken.Register(() => webClient.CancelAsync()))
{
    text = await downloadTask;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's still there in .Net 4.5 beta, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138332%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), except it's not an extension method anymore.

What you may be referring to is the fact that `WebClient` is not included in .Net for Metro-style apps. There, you should probably use `HttpClient`. Another option is to use `HttpWebRequest`, which is still present and has been extended with `Task`-based async methods as well.

Comment: The Method is still there but not the overload that takes the CancellationToken, all the examples I could find seems to be based on the CTP. I think HttpWebRequest is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry I meant HttpClient.GetStringAsync

Answer (score 0):

Both classes System.Net.WebClient and System.Net.Http.HttpClient have an async function. This enables you to create an async function. While the GetStringAsync function is running asynchronously you can check regularly if cancellation is requested.

Example:
    using System.Net.Http;
    class HttpSonnetFetcher
    {
        const string sonnetsShakespeare = @"http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1041/pg1041.txt";

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Fetch(CancellationToken token)
    {
        string bookShakespeareSonnets = null;
        using (var downloader = new HttpClient())
        {
            var downloadTask = downloader.GetStringAsync(sonnetsShakespeare);
            // wait until downloadTask finished, but regularly check if cancellation requested:
            while (!downloadTask.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2)))
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
            // if still here: downloadTask completed
            bookShakespeareSonnets = downloadTask.Result;
        }

        // just for fun: find a nice sonnet, remove the beginning, split into lines and return 12 lines
        var indexNiceSonnet = bookShakespeareSonnets.IndexOf("Shall I compare thee to a summer's day?");
        return bookShakespeareSonnets.Remove(0, indexNiceSonnet)
            .Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Take(12);  
    }
}
```

Usage will be as follows:

```
private void TestCancellationHttpClient()
{
    try
    {
        var sonnetFetcher = new HttpSonnetFetcher();
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var sonnetTask = Task.Run(() => sonnetFetcher.Fetch(cancellationTokenSource.Token));
        cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        // meanwhile do something else, checking regularly if the task finished, or if you have nothing to do, just Task.Wait():
        while (!sonnetTask.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25)))
        {
            Console.Write('.');
        }
        // if still here: the sonnet is fetched. return value is in sonnetTask.Result
        Console.WriteLine("A nice sonnet by William Shakespeare:");
        foreach (var line in sonnetTask.Result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }

    catch (OperationCanceledException exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Canceled " + exc.Message);
    }
    catch (AggregateException exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task reports exceptions");
        var x = exc.Flatten();
        foreach (var innerException in x.InnerExceptions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(innerException.Message);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + exc.Message);
    }
}
```

Try this in a simple console program, and see that the sonnet is fetched properly, Decrease CancelAfter from 10 seconds until, say 0.1 second, and see that the task is properly cancelled.

> Nota Bene: Although an OperationCancelledException is thrown, this exception is wrapped as an inner exception of an AggregateException. All exceptions that occur within a task are always wrapped in an AggregateException.